"piena quaggiù"
In questa poesia di Pasolini, ho qualche difficoltà qui:

Ecco nel calore incantato
della notte che piena quaggiù
tra le curve del fiume e le sopite
visioni della città sparsa di luci,
scheggia ancora di mille vite,
disamore, mistero, e miseria
dei sensi, mi rendono nemiche
le forme del mondo, che fino a ieri
erano la mia ragione d’esistere.

Ho un dubbio con "piena". È una forma del verbo "pienare" oppure una forma del aggettivo "pieno"? Sarei in favore del verbo, però non è che il verbo "pienare" aspetta un complemento diretto? E quale sarebbe questo complemento diretto? "quaggiù"? Ma il complemento di luogo non è piuttosto "quaggiù tra le curve del fiume e le sopite visioni della città sparsa di luci"?

Non è una risposta, ma solo un commento perché anch'io sono incerto. Intanto inserirei tutto il periodo, che così com'è è incompleto. Poi, “pienare” come verbo mi suona molto insolito; il Treccani lo dà come “tosc. pop. e ant.”. Ora, Pasolini non era toscano, né antico. E quanto a registro popolare, ne attingeva a piene mani, ma in genere o dal suo nativo friulano o dal romanesco d'adozione. Ma la mia è solo un'opinione a orecchio.

@DaG Ho inserito tutto il periodo (mi sembrava troppo lungo, ma sbagliavo).

Non è facile, a prima vista si direbbe un attributo di notte, ma c'è quel che davanti che lo rende dubbio. Sono d'accordo con DaG sul fatto che il verbo pienare è inconsueto, ma vedi ad esempio questa voce dell'Accademia della Crusca, che parla del suo uso antico https://accademiadellacrusca.it/it/consulenza/a-proposito-del-verbo-pienare/996. Mi sembra plausibile che Pasolini lo usi come verbo, i poeti fanno un po' come gli pare, me lo suggerisce quello che viene dopo, le anse, le visioni delle città tra cui la notte si insinua, come a riempire i vuoti dei profili.  Ma va approfondito.

@BakerStreet L'italiano non è la mia madrelingua e quindi non so come suona ad un Italiano. Non conoscevo il verbo "pienare", l'ho trovato su Treccani. Se è un aggettivo, allora "che" è il soggetto di "scheggia" (ma non manca una virgola tra "che" e "piena" per questa interpretazione?)?

A un italiano 'pienare' suona insolito, ma la poesia è un'altra cosa, non è il linguaggio comune, si trova di tutto,  ed è possibile che un poeta abbia consuetudine con un verbo usato nella letteratura più antica e da lì lo usi. Che non credo possa  essere il soggetto di scheggia, che credo sia un sostantivo.  Nel caso che piena sia un aggettivo, l'unica ipotesi che mi viene in mente è che sia sottinteso è, la notte che è piena quaggiù, ma mi sembra un po' artificioso.

@Bruno hai scritto: "ma non manca una virgola tra "che" e "piena" per questa interpretazione?)?". Qui hai ragione, ma quando leggi poesia in italiano non stare troppo a pensare alla punteggiatura standard, non è detto che sia rispettata come in uno scritto normale, e in genere alle regole, si può trovare di tutto, anche nel lessico, la poesia italiana è difficilissima. In particolare quella del '900.

Però ripensando potrebbe essere piena un  aggettivo e scheggia, da scheggiare,   un verbo, usato insolitamente in senso intransitivo, su Treccani non c'è, senza complemento, come a dire 'manda schegge, scintille' di mille vite. La frase così sarebbe più piana  e naturale, mi sembra abbastanza convincente, a parte questo uso idiosincratico di scheggiare. Che non ci sia la virgola non ha importanza.

@BakerStreet Cercando con Google ho trovato questo documento: https://www.palumboeditore.it/insiemeperlascuola/contenuti/assets/pdf/ddi/ldi_pasolini.pdf C'è questa parafrase (p. 863): "Nel calore incantato [: magico] della notte fonda (piena) che ancora risuona
(echeggia) di mille [: numerose; indetermi-
nato] vite, quaggiù tra le curve del fiume
[Tevere] e le visioni sfumate (sopite = ad-
dormentate) della città [: Roma] dissemina-
ta (sparsa) di luci". Una cosa mi stupisce: "scheggia" è diventato "echeggia". Ci sono due versioni di questa poesia?!

Bizzarro. Mi sa che nel testo che hai riportato nel tuo post c'è un refuso, e il testo autentico dice echeggia. Il documento che hai linkato è un libro stampato, mi pare, quindi più attendibile. Il refuso spiegherebbe l'oscurità del testo che hai riportato nella domanda. Comunque cercherò di controllare.

Ho controllato sulla edizione Garzanti: https://www.amazon.it/ceneri-Gramsci-Pier-Paolo-Pasolini/dp/8811688744/ref=sr_1_1?crid=2ORF98HBHC47D&dib=eyJ2IjoiMSJ9.CVTBFYK0Q8LjAKsi6Gz5U-xZ9qpMdfJnIj0503SU2alB2jX2VZ7PurDEQRDku6-m7uldVnMoCJ_f1P6Q1oZFYKarhGuUmKlNIEQphyh38DcUlLIEVnvCYZSp-PpF2FG38klT295BJISOHFv4Yxs-KWfWAm__p5OzzR9YtwvIjB6mSIol_EdkgltrIW2VTpP76FqhoIrbr9B8iV92JABJO592qct8MrlB6vYd-DT_CsC-OmwF5Fy6XhNmkQfWj0-9mnwCeAEq0BbbCXkUEvVA.K86yEyiM1bma7a4gHnEL0jCR0nnSa58D-HbpW7fYAs0&dib_tag=se&keywords=pasolini+le+ceneri+di+gramsci&nsdOptOutParam=true&qid=1733357148&sprefix=%2Caps%2C300&sr=8-1.

Il testo sulla edizione Garzanti dice echeggia. Probabilmente  scheggia è stato un errore di chi sa  chi che poi è stato ripreso in  vari testi della poesia che girano su internet.

Chiarito il mistero, Bruno o @BakerStreet vogliono scrivere una risposta che compendia questo scambio di commenti?

@DaG Grazie, lascio l'onore e l'onere a Bruno, se vuole, che ha scoperto l'errore ed è l'autore della domanda.

Il testo della domanda è sbagliato. Pasolini ha scritto "echeggia" e non "scheggia". Con "echeggia" invece di "scheggia" capiamo che il "che" del secondo verso è il soggetto di "echeggia" e che la parola "piena" è qui un aggettivo.
